# Stream to Image and back

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, filestream

I'm taking a `Stream` convert it to `Image`, process that image, then return a `FileStream`.

Is this a performance problem? If not, whats the optimized way to convert and return back a stream?

```
public FileStream ResizeImage(int h, int w, Stream stream)
{
       var img = Image.FromStream(stream);

       /* ..Processing.. */

       //converting back to stream? is this right?
       img.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);

       return stream;
}
```

The situation in which this is running: User uploads image on my site (controller gives me a Stream, i resize this, then send this stream to rackspace (Rackspace takes a `FileStream`).

Comment: Are you _having_ a performance problem?

Comment: @Oded, I dont have to be having a performance problem to write optimized code from the start.

Comment: It depends on the optimization. If you _know_ the code is performing badly, yes, do optimize. But the rule should be: measure before optimizing.

Comment: I didn't know how to do it anyways so might as well find out the most effecient way to do it while asking :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You basically want something like this, don't you:

```
public void Resize(Stream input, Stream output, int width, int height)
{
    using (var image = Image.FromStream(input))
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height))
    using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        gr.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
        gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
        gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        gr.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
        bmp.Save(output, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

which will be used like this:

```
using (var input = File.OpenRead("input.jpg"))
using (var output = File.Create("output.png"))
{
    Resize(input, output, 640, 480);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks as simple as it can be. You have to read the entire image contents to be able to process it and you have to write the result back.

FileStreams are the normal .NET way to handle files, so for normal purposes your approach is okay.

The only thing I don't understand is why you return the FileStream again - it is the same object as was passed by a parameter.

If you are doing a lot of images and only modify parts of the data, memory mapped files could improve performance. However it is a more advanced concept to use.